# forms.modelform ordering?

Tags: django, forms

```
class OperationCategoryOnlyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Operation
      fields = ('operation_type', 'category', 'related_account', )
      ordering = ['date']


OperationFormSet = modelformset_factory(Operation, form=OperationCategoryOnlyForm)
```

this is very easy question - why it doesn't work, and what to do to get it sorted different than default (by id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ordering` is not a valid option for a model form's `Meta` class, so specifying it won't do anything.

If you always want to order the model by a particular field, you can simply set [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) in the model's `Meta` class. This will affect the ordering in other places e.g. in the django admin.

```
class Operation(models.Model):
    # field definitions
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date',)
```

If you only want to change the ordering for this formset, [provide a custom queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) when you initialize it.

```
OperationFormSet = modelformset_factory(Operation, form=OperationCategoryOnlyForm, queryset=Operation.objects.order_by('date'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much... Full answer, more than I expected.